# How to find the threshold that minimizes the (weighted) mis-classification rate?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, decision-theory, threshold

To use a logistic regression model for doing prediction, let
\begin{equation}
    \hat Y_i=
   \begin{cases}
   1 &\mbox{if $P(Y_i=1|X_i)>\alpha$}\\
   0 &\mbox{if $P(Y_i=1|X_i)\leq\alpha$}
   \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

where $\alpha$ is the threshold, *i.e.*, $P(Y_i=1|X_i)$ is estimated by logistic regression, and if $P(Y_i=1|X_i)>\alpha$, $\hat Y_i=1$, otherwise, $\hat Y_i=0$.

The mis-classification rate is defined as 
                    $\mbox{MCR}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mI\{Y_i\neq \hat Y_i\}$.

The weighted mis-classification rate (assigning higher weights to rare events) is defined as 
                    $\mbox{WMCR}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m\left\{
\frac{I\{Y_i\neq \hat Y_i|Y_i=0\}}{P(Y_i=0)} +
\frac{I\{Y_i\neq \hat Y_i|Y_i=1\}}{P(Y_i=1)}
\right\}$.

It is known that the mis-classification rate is minimized when $\alpha=0.5$ and under certain conditions the weighted mis-classification rate is minimized when $\alpha=P(Y_i=1)$.

Could anyone please let me know how these minimization problems are solved?

Comment: For clarity, you might use $\hat y_i$ for predicted classes, instead of $Y$. At any rate, setting $\alpha = 0.5$ will only minimize the misclassification rate if the proportion of positive classes in your sample is $50\%$.

Comment: @gung Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated my question accordingly.  I understand that the choice of  $\alpha=0.5$ may be problematic, I just want to know how to solve the minimization problems. Thanks.